# How to make "rand()" generate actual random numbers?

Tags: c, random

I got this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int rand();

int main()
{
        int a = 1;

        while (a<=15)
        {
                printf("%d\n", rand());
                a++;
        }

        return 0;

}
```

The function to generate random numbers generate the same numbers in every execution, how do I fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initalise your `rand()` with `srand()` like so :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a = 1;

    while (a<=15)
    {
            printf("%d\n", rand());
            a++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In short, you need to feed your random some seeds so it can do his work, but you want to give him new seeds at each run, thus the use of `time(NULL)`.

Oh, and also, you don't need to declare `int rand();` before your main, but instead add `<stdlib.h>` to your list of includes.

Keep up the learning !

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a seed so just do this before your while loop (Also don't forget to include: `time.h`):

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can generate different random numbers by using

```
#include <stdlib.h>   // for rand() and srand()
#include <time.h>     // for time()
// other headers

int main()
{
  srand(time(NULL));
  // rest of your code
}
```

By using `srand()`, you can seed the Random Number generator to get different random numbers on different runs of the program.

And also remove `int rand();` from your code, unless you are trying to create your own `rand()` function

Answer (score 1):

Seet seed or `srand(time(NULL));`

If u set with time, include `<time.h>` library.

I recomended you `include <stdlib.h>` - this is for srand or rand function.